# Using IN expression in Order By clause

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I properly use the IN expression in Order By clause? I have a few questions like this and I cannot find a solution.

I want to select ID, lastname, country from the customer list and order it by the north american countries first (canada and usa, with corresponding ID) then once those have populated, I want to order the remaining data based on ID alone.

```
Select customerid, lastname, country
From customer
Where country IN ('Canada', 'USA')
Order By CustomerID
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBhq2.gif) is what they are looking for.

I have tried Where clause and nesting the query but I am new to this.

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: What's the issue you're facing?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use `where` criteria, but rather conditional ordering:

```
Select customerid, lastname, country
From customer
Order By country IN ('Canada', 'USA') desc, CustomerID
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46390/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can also write a `case` in your `order by` to get more options.

**[sqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d204/3)**

```
Select customerid, lastname, country
From customer
Order By 
    CASE 
        WHEN country IN ('Canada', 'USA')  THEN 1
        ELSE 2
    END as order_id
    , CustomerID
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!